# What's the Javascript 'delete' keyword equivalent in Lua?

Tags: lua

Javascript delete keyword deletes a named variable slot from nearest execution environment which it defined.
What's the equivalent in Lua?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var = nil
```

Environments in Lua are tables, and tables cannot contain nil value - assigning nil to a key in a table effectively deletes that key from the table.

Here is [a quote from "Programming in Lua"](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html):

> Like global variables, table fields
>   evaluate to nil if they are not
>   initialized. Also like global
>   variables, you can assign nil to a
>   table field to delete it. That is not
>   a coincidence: Lua stores global
>   variables in ordinary tables

Comment: Note that this doesn't always work as expected. If you have a function that accepts an optional argument of a certain type and throws an error if the argument is falsy (`nil` or `false`) it will throw an error if you try to "delete" a variable being passed as argument using this method.